# How best can I to pivot my redshift table?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift table called `metadata` with the following columns:

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | code1 | my value |
| 1001 | code2 | another |
| 1001 | code3 | yet another |
| 1002 | code1 | new one |
| 1002 | code2 | here |
| 1002 | code3 | last |
| 1003 | code1 | hello |
| 1003 | code2 | goodbye |
| 1004 | code2 | now |
| 1004 | code3 | then |

I'd like to have a query that return it as:

| id | code1 | code2 | code3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | my value | another | yet another |
| 1002 | new one | here | last |
| 1003 | hello | goodbye |  |
| 1004 |  | now | then |

Note that not all ID's will have all 3 codes. Some will have 1 or 2 of them, others all 3, and others still, none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Assuming you know the columns you want in the result set, you can use:

```
select id,
       max(case when key = 'code1' then value end) as code1,
       max(case when key = 'code2' then value end) as code2,
       max(case when key = 'code3' then value end) as code3
from t
group by id;
```

If you don't know the specific values and need to read them from the data . . . that is trickier.  As far as I know, Redshift doesn't support dynamic SQL.  So, you would need to query the database for the different `key` values and construct a query as a string using your favorite language.  You can then execute that query.

Comment: Thanks - I realized I didnt include another requirement/use case. There may or may not be all three "code" columns, or any combination of them, or sometimes none at all.  So one row may have all 3, another only code1 and code2, another may have none.

Comment: @BenShichman . . . You should ask a new question.  Changing this question after it has been answered only threatens to invalidate what was a correct answer.